# Big confusion about the very fundamentals of circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, basic, thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws, superposition

[image]

First, let's call IR3 the current flowing from A to B, IR4 the current flowing from B to C, IR5 the current flowing from C  to (-V2).

What's the proof that IR3>0, IR4>0 and IR5>0?

I know this question is weird but I just want a clear, formal answer.

I know that, intuitively, the answer is obvious; But I challenged myself to provide an answer that is completely independent of intuition.

The reason why I'm doing this is that when the circuit becomes a little more complex (i.e adding diodes and generators), you have then to take guesses that some call "hypotheses" that are later confirmed or disproved. I need to know that there always exists a (relatively simple) way to be able to work without putting any hypotheses.

I would also like to point out that I've already found a formal answer, but it's very tedious and consumed a lot of time:

- I wrote three different mesh equations (from three different meshes). I wrote each equation as a linear combination where resistances are the parameters and currents (IR3, IR4 and IR5) are the  variables, and on the other side of the equation I had a linear combination of V1 and V2
- Then I transformed the system into a matrix equation A.X=B where X is the one column matrix of (IR3, IR4 and IR5)
- Then I solved the equation by writing A^(-1) that contained a lot of different combinations of the resistances, and by multiplying by B
- Finally, after some simplifications, I got a 1x3 matrix in which each line was in the form of ***[a combination of resistances].V1+[another combination of resistances].V2***
- The last result consists what I consider as a formal proof that IR3, IR4 and IR5 are all positive. But it's obviously a very tedious answer (imagine if we added two more resistances, following the existing pattern, the equations get more and more complicated).

I also tried to prove only by Millman's theorem that potential at B has a lesser value (not absolute value) than A and that the potential at C has a lesser value than B and that (-V2) has a lesser value than the potential at C.

While trying this option, I wrote Milmann's expressions of Vb and Vc, which gave me another matrix equation A.X=B where X contained Vb and Vc. Writing A^(-1) using resistances was also tedious and when I solved the equation, I just didn't know what to do with the expressions (i.e. how to use them to verify the comparisons mentioned above). So I abandoned this attempt.

Another attempt is to calculate the Thevenin equivalents of the circuit between C and D (R5, V2, R2) and the circuit between B and E (R1, R3, V1). This gives us three resistances (Rth1, R4 and Rth2) in series that are placed between a positive potential(Vth1) and a negative potential (-Vth2), and since current travels across passive dipoles from the big potential toward the smaller potential, we can say that we've proven that IR4 is positive; But this doesn't give us any direct information about IR3 and IR5.

[image]

When trying the Superposition theorem, we start by replacing V2 with a closed circuit, we then have V1 feeding the equivalent resistance; which proves that IR3 is positive when V2=0, but this doesn't tell us about the signs of IR4 and IR5 when V2=0, and here's why: if IR3 is positive then Vb<Va, but this doens't prove that Va>0 (in order for the current from B to E to be positive) and it doesn't prove that Vb>Vc (in order for the current from B to C to be positive). When we replace by V1=0 we have symmetrical results, but the results are not complementary enough to add the final currents.

Maybe I should try Millman's matrix equation (see above) while applying the superposition theorem, which will give us two matrix equations, and I don't even know if they'll produce any expressions that are exploitable...

I also tried to use the generalized KCL by trying to apply it on any closed surface in the circuit, but I found nothing interesting...

Maybe I should consider a quadrupole... but I'm not good at those yet...

My question is: how can we give a formal, mathematical, abstract proof, that is completely independent of intuition, that is generated from the basic circuit analysis tools (Ohm, Kirchhoff, Millman, Thevenin, Norton, Superposition theorem) but that is also simple, uses the same method for IR3, IR4 and IR5 and is non tedious, and that we can easily generalize for n Resistances. Either I'm missing something embarrassingly obvious, or this shows that circuit analysis depends heavily on assumptions that may seem intuitive but have tedious proofs, which is a huge problem in my opinion; It's like the fundamentals aren't enough to prove themselves (except by going trough tedious calculations). But I must be missing something very obvious...

Comment: hint: things get way less confusing when you call currents like the resistors they flow through – your I_1 would be my I_3, for example.

Comment: *What's the proof that I1>0* - try finding a proof that makes I1=0 i.e. by making R1 and R2 infinity and by making V2 = -V1. That's the case for zero current. Doesn't seem a big deal to me. Or keep R2 finite and make V2 = -1 x R2/(R5+R2). Unsure what the problem is here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited the currents, is this what you meant?

Comment: @Andyaka in the first section of your comment, you said "try finding a proof that makes I1=0" and the conditions you gave actually show that I1=0, but how does that answer my question, how does that give us a simple, formal proof, issued from the basic tools of circuit analysis that those currents are positive and not negative? In the second part of your comment, that has the shape of a voltage divider, but it's not, I didn't understand it, and I didn't understand how it relates to my question. Which part of my question is unclear?

Comment: I read it as magnitude of current is greater than 0. You are actually looking to uncover sign information, yes? Well, finding the limit when the current is zero allows you to test the direction of current through differentiation maybe.

Comment: What are these "hypotheses" that must be made before solving the circuit you present? I don't see any hypotheses, just labels for currents. Also, don't confuse the analysis of linear circuits with the analysis of non-linear circuits (e.g. with diodes).

Comment: @ElliotAlderson In my question, I said: "when the circuit becomes a little more complex (i.e adding diodes and generators), you have THEN to take guesses that some call "hypotheses" that are later confirmed or disproved."

The circuit that I present doesn't require such hypotheses but these questions arose when I was solving a similar circuit but with diodes in it.

Comment: So show us a circuit that actually relates to your question, or change the text to match the schematic. Right now your question is very poorly defined. Why must there be a "proof" that is not tedious?

Comment: Changing the question fundamentally or extending it significantly once an answer is given is bad form in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

> *Another attempt is to calculate the Thevenin equivalents of the circuit.......we've proven that IR4 is positive; But this doesn't give us any direct
> information about IR3 and IR5.*

It pretty much does: -

[image]

So, IR4 is clearly positive and easily calculated.

**Edited section**

The node voltages are easily calculated from IR4 and then the original current through R3 can be calculated. I accept that the current in R3 in the converted circuit isn't the same as the current in the original circuit.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your comments, answers and efforts.

Comment: Concerning your answer, I still can't connect it to my question, here's why:

The current flowing through (R3||R1) is between the potentials V1.R1/(R1+R3) and Vb, whereas IR3 flows between V1 and Vb. You say IR3 is the proportion of IR4 taking into account the values of R1 and R3. However, I couldn't extract a formula where IR3=Const. *IR4

Comment: After the transformation, R3 and its voltage drop are no longer physically present on the circuit... I don't see how we can talk about the current flowing in a resistance that doesn't exist...

Comment: OK so the current isn't the same. I accept that (my mistake) but, you've found the current that flows through R4 and, with a tiny bit of number crunching you can calculate the node voltages and work out the original current through R3.

Comment: @Andyaka I agree with your last comment.

Comment: However, when trying to apply it, it gives a relatively long demonstration (not as long as the matrix equation solution though). In my opinion, this doesn't disprove my concern about the possibility that basic circuit analysis depends heavily on intuitive assumptions ("IR3, IR4 and IR5 are all positive because we have a positive potential on the left and a negative potential on the right so the current must generally flow from left to right") that are not so easy to prove.

Comment: Here's a link showing photos of the "relatively long demonstration" I mentionned:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/193933319@N08/?

Comment: I’m not trying to disprove anything. I just don’t feel your dilemma about things.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway for the effort and patience.